# How can I access cpu temperature readings using c#?

Tags: cpu, c#, windows-installer, temperature

For a programming project I would like to access the temperature readings from my CPU and GPUs.  I will be using C#.
From various forums I get the impression that there is specific information and developer resources you need in order to access that information for various boards.
I have a MSI NF750-G55 board.  MSI's website does not have any of the information I am looking for.  I tried their tech support and the rep I spoke with stated they do not have any such information.
There must be a way to obtain that info.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You may want to try Stackoverflow.com since this is more programming related.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CPU temperature monitoring C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923984/cpu-temperature-monitoring-c)

Comment: This question was re-asked moments later, got more useful answers, we should close this one.

Answer (score 1):

If the vendor does not have a api or provider, you are most likely out of luck.

HP for example has a very extensive WMI provider for their ProLiant models, and it is fairly trivial to use the  System.Management namespace to perform WMI queries to get this information using C#, PowerShell, VBScript, etc.