# How can I read CPU temperature on an Embedded XP install from a C++/CLI app?

Tags: c++-cli, cpu, temperature

I've read of [some WMI solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923984/cpu-temperature-monitoring-c) which are able to read the temperature of the CPU. I've tried this and it doesn't appear to work for Windows XP Embedded running on an Intel Atom based board.

Is there a library or some other solution out there which would work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like [Core Temp](http://www.alcpu.com/CoreTemp/developers.html) could be a viable solution.