# How to get the CPU Temperature info from Bios using c#?

Tags: monitoring, c#

How to get the CPU Temperature info from Bios using c# I gave a try to the code in [CPU temperature monitoring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923984/cpu-temperature-monitoring-c)

But no luck. `enumerator.Current` threw an exception.

How can i achieve this ? Thanks.

Error :

```
"This system doesn't support the required WMI objects(1) - check the exception file 
Not supported 

 at System.Management.ManagementException.ThrowWithExtendedInfo(ManagementStatus errorCode)
 at System.Management.ManagementObjectCollection.ManagementObjectEnumerator.MoveNext()
 at CedarLogic.WmiLib.SystemStatistics.RefreshReadings() in D:\Downloads\TempMonitorSrc\TemperatureMonitorSln\WmiLib\SystemStatistics.cs:line 25
 at CedarLogic.WmiLib.SystemStatistics.get_CurrentTemperature() in D:\Downloads\TempMonitorSrc\TemperatureMonitorSln\WmiLib\SystemStatistics.cs:line 87
 at TemperatureMonitor.SystemTrayService.CheckSupport() in D:\Downloads\TempMonitorSrc\TemperatureMonitorSln\TemperatureMonitor\SystemTrayService.cs:line 260"
```

Comment: This would be more appropriate on StackOverflow.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [OpenHardwareMonitor](http://openhardwaremonitor.org/).

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the exact same problem:

https://superuser.com/questions/183282/cant-query-cpu-temperature-msacpi-thermalzonetemperature-on-windows-embedded-7

The code in the link you cited is correct.  My .exe works fine on Windows/XP and Windows/Vista (as long as I "run as Administrator" on Vista) ... but fails with the WMI error "not supported" on Windows Embedded 7.

At this point, I don't know if the problem is the OS (WES7) or my motherboard (an Intel DH57jg).

Answer (score 0):

Although not ideal, the closest/best solution I have found is to use [Speedfan](http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php) (free), which can expose its probe information to external applications, via a memory-map. Somebody has done the C# conversion:

[Reading SpeedFan shared memory with C#](http://bluesplat-tech.blogspot.com/2009/09/reading-speedfan-shared-memory-with-c.html)

> "Building on what I spoke about in my
>   previous post, lets say we want to
>   access the data that SpeedFan provides
>   from a C# application. As a small
>   aside, reading information from the
>   SMBus and other low level interfaces
>   can only be done from the kernel. So
>   applications like SpeedFan (HWMonitor,
>   Everest, etc etc) generally run a
>   driver at kernel level and then a
>   front-end GUI to present the
>   information.
>
> In the case of SpeedFan, shared memory
>   (actually its technically a memory
>   mapped file on Windows I think) is
>   used to communicate between the kernel
>   driver and the userspace GUI
>   application. Even better, the format
>   of this file has been made public by
>   the author of SpeedFan. So, enough
>   talk, lets see some code!"