# PHP and Windows WMI, CPU Temperature and false readings?

Tags: php, function, wmi, cpu

I wrote this PHP function:

```
<?php
//windows cpu temperature
function win_cpu_temp(){
    $wmi = new COM("winmgmts://./root\WMI");
    $cpus = $wmi->execquery("SELECT * FROM MSAcpi_ThermalZoneTemperature");
    foreach ($cpus as $cpu) {
        $cpupre = $cpu->CurrentTemperature;
    }
    $cpu_temp = ($cpupre/10)-273.15 . ' C';
    return $cpu_temp;
}
echo win_cpu_temp();
?>
```

My problem, is that the script displays `59.55 C` which I had thought was correct. I checked this value several hours later, and it's exactly the same. I just put the CPU to work at 90% compressing video for ten minutes, and this value is the same still.

Can anyone help me find the "true" value for this function?

I've read (to no avail):
[MSAcpi_ThermalZoneTemperature class not showing actual temperature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9101295/msacpi-thermalzonetemperature-class-not-showing-actual-temperature)

How is, say, "Core Temp" getting its values? Same computer, it reports between 49 and 53 Celsius.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With a little digging around I found the common issue with using MSAcpi_ThermalZoneTemperature was that it is dependent upon being implemented on your system.

You could try querying [Win32_TemperatureProbe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394493%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and see if you have any luck there.

Neither MSAcpi_ThermalZoneTemperature or Win32_TemperatureProbe worked on my system, although if you have admin access, you can use http://openhardwaremonitor.org/ which provides a WMI interface for all available sensor data.

This worked great for me and I was able to accurately report CPU Core temp from a PHP script:

```
function report_cpu_temp(){    
    $wmi = new COM('winmgmts://./root/OpenHardwareMonitor');
    $result = $wmi->ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Sensor");
    foreach($result as $obj){
        if($obj->SensorType == 'Temperature' && strpos($obj->Parent, 'cpu') > 0)
            echo "$obj->Name ($obj->Value C)"; // output cpu core temp
        else
            echo 'skipping ' . $obj->Identifier ;
        echo '<br />';
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This didn't work as-written on any of my systems, but I see where its going and will modify it accordingly.

Comment: Works perfectly for me, just copy and paste code.. Ran perfectly.. Thanks, such as simple and good solution.