# Getting CPU information from Python WMI

Tags: python, wmi

I am trying to get some system information from Pythons WMI module however allot of the methods mention online don't seem to be working. I know it is easier to do it in other languages but I want to try and do this in Python for reasons.

I have tried using the `Win32_TemperatureProbe()` method but I get a return value of `None`. I have also tried the `MSAcpi_ThermalZoneTemperature()` and the error for that is below. I have been doing my research and can't seem to find any alternative methods or fixes to these errors. There seem to be allot of threads open but none solved.

Here is my current code:

```
import wmi, platform

#Initiating WMI
c = wmi.WMI(namespace="root\\wmi")

#Setting variables
drive_letter, free_space = [], []
stats = {}

#Getting basic infromation
print(platform.processor())
print(c.MSAcpi_ThermalZoneTemperature()[0].CurrentTemperature/10.0)-273.15

for disk in c.Win32_LogicalDisk(["Caption","FreeSpace"], DriveType=3):
   free_space_GB = round(int((disk.FreeSpace))/1073741824, 2)
   drive_letter.append(str(disk.Caption))
   free_space.append(str(free_space_GB))

stats = {"Free Space":free_space, "Drive Letter":drive_letter}

print(stats)
```

and here is the output I get when running this code:

```
Intel64 Family 6 Model 60 Stepping 3, GenuineIntel
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\wmi.py", line 817, in query
    return self._namespace.query (wql, self, fields)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\wmi.py", line 1009, in query
    return [ _wmi_object (obj, instance_of, fields) for obj in self._raw_query(wql) ]
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\wmi.py", line 1009, in <listcomp>
    return [ _wmi_object (obj, instance_of, fields) for obj in self._raw_query(wql) ]
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 247, in __getitem__
    return self._get_good_object_(self._enum_.__getitem__(index))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\util.py", line 37, in __getitem__
    return self.__GetIndex(index)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\util.py", line 53, in __GetIndex
    result = self._oleobj_.Next(1)
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147217396, 'OLE error 0x8004100c', None, None)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Brandyn\Desktop\Performance_monitor.py", line 12, in <module>
    print(c.MSAcpi_ThermalZoneTemperature()[0].CurrentTemperature/10.0)-273.15
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\wmi.py", line 819, in query
    handle_com_error ()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\wmi.py", line 241, in handle_com_error
    raise klass (com_error=err)
wmi.x_wmi: <x_wmi: Unexpected COM Error (-2147217396, 'OLE error 0x8004100c', None, None)>
```

When I change the namespace to null, the error changes to this:

```
Intel64 Family 6 Model 60 Stepping 3, GenuineIntel
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\wmi.py", line 1145, in __getattr__
    return self._cached_classes (attribute)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\wmi.py", line 1156, in _cached_classes
    self._classes_map[class_name] = _wmi_class (self, self._namespace.Get (class_name))
  File "<COMObject winmgmts:>", line 3, in Get
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 282, in _ApplyTypes_
    result = self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(*(dispid, LCID, wFlags, retType, argTypes) + args)
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'SWbemServicesEx', 'Not found ', None, 0, -2147217406), None)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Brandyn\Desktop\Performance_monitor.py", line 12, in <module>
    print(c.MSAcpi_ThermalZoneTemperature()[0].CurrentTemperature/10.0)-273.15
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\wmi.py", line 1147, in __getattr__
    return getattr (self._namespace, attribute)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 522, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError("%s.%s" % (self._username_, attr))
AttributeError: winmgmts:.MSAcpi_ThermalZoneTemperature
```

Is there a fix to this method or is there another viable alternative or should I just simply stop this and focus on a different language?

Comment: I got the same issue, were you able to find a sollution for your problem? Or any solution to find CPU temp on windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue.

For `Win32_LogicalDisk`, you need to replace namespace `root\\wmi` with `root\\cimv2`. 
Then it worked for me on Win7.

For `MSAcpi_ThermalZoneTemperature`, I have not found a solution. The object looks as follows

```
    >>> print c.MSAcpi_ThermalZoneTemperature
[dynamic: ToInstance, provider("WMIProv"), WMI, guid("{A1BC18C0-A7C8-11d1-BF3C-00A0C9062910}")]
class MSAcpi_ThermalZoneTemperature : MSAcpi
{
    [key, read] string InstanceName;
    [read] boolean Active;
    [WmiDataId(1), read] uint32 ThermalStamp;
    [WmiDataId(2), read] uint32 ThermalConstant1;
    [WmiDataId(3), read] uint32 ThermalConstant2;
    [WmiDataId(4), read] uint32 Reserved;
    [WmiDataId(5), read] uint32 SamplingPeriod;
    [WmiDataId(6), read] uint32 CurrentTemperature;
    [WmiDataId(7), read] uint32 PassiveTripPoint;
    [WmiDataId(8), read] uint32 CriticalTripPoint;
    [WmiDataId(9), read] uint32 ActiveTripPointCount;
    [WmiDataId(10), MissingValue(0), read, MAX(10)] uint32 ActiveTripPoint[];
};
```

BUT `c.MSAcpi_ThermalZoneTemperature.CurrentTemperature` returns `None`.

Interesting is if we run folliwing code

```
import win32com.client
strComputer = "."
objWMIService = win32com.client.Dispatch("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator")
objSWbemServices = objWMIService.ConnectServer(strComputer,"root\WMI")
colItems = objSWbemServices.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM MSAcpi_ThermalZoneTemperature")
print repr(colItems)
print len(colItems)
```

then calling `print repr(colItems)` returns `<COMObject <unknown>>`
and calling `print len(colItems)` generates an exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get_wmi_test1.py", line 45, in <module>
    print len(colItems)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 228, in
__len__
    return self._oleobj_.Invoke(dispid, LCID, invkind, 1)
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, u'SWbemObjectSet'
, u'Not supported ', None, 0, -2147217396), None)
```

I looked a bit around and seems to be more complex issue. Look here:

- [MSAcpi_ThermalZoneTemperature not showing temperature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9101295/msacpi-thermalzonetemperature-class-not-showing-actual-temperature)
- [How to enable WMI on windows 7](http://www.enviris.com/blog/7-how-to-enable-wmi-on-windows-7.aspx)