# (C#, WMI) Tray App Displaying CPU Temp only updates value when SpeedFan App is running

Tags: c#, timer, wmi, temp, trayicon

I've made a simple tray app that displays the CPU Temperature and updates every second using a timer.

The tray icon displays the "CurrentTemperature" parameter retrieved from the ManagementObjectSearcher query, which is then used to create a Bitmap that displays the temperature value.

It seems to be working well, except for the fact that it **always retrieves the exact same temperature value**. However, if I have [SpeedFan](http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php) running in the background, the **temperature will update accordingly**.

Could anyone provide me with insight as to why the app is unable to retrieve the updated temperature value on its own?

*Note: I've checked my machine's BIOS and there are no temperature readings*

I'm attaching the code for anyone interested / willing to give advice

```
class Program
{
    private static System.Timers.Timer tmr;
    private static ContextMenu CMenu;
    private static NotifyIcon trayIcon;
    private static Color c;
    private static int Temp;
    private static int _Temp;

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        tmr = new System.Timers.Timer();
        trayIcon = new NotifyIcon();
        CMenu = new ContextMenu();

        //ContextMenu
        CMenu.MenuItems.Add("Exit", Exit_Application);

        //trayIcon
        trayIcon.ContextMenu = CMenu;
        trayIcon.Visible = true;

        //Timer
        tmr.Interval = 1000;
        tmr.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(onTimerTick);
        tmr.Enabled = true;

        Temp = 0;
        Application.Run();
    }
    private static void Exit_Application(object Sender, EventArgs e) { trayIcon.Icon = null; Application.Exit(); }

    private static void onTimerTick(object Sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        using (ManagementObjectSearcher mos = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\WMI", "SELECT * FROM MSAcpi_ThermalZoneTemperature"))
        {
            using (ManagementObject mo = mos.Get().OfType<ManagementObject>().First())
            {
                _Temp = int.Parse(mo["CurrentTemperature"].ToString()) / 10 - 273; //Convert To Celsius
                if (_Temp != Temp)
                {
                    Temp = _Temp;
                    trayIcon.Icon = CreateIcon(Temp);
                }
                if (Temp >= 85) { Console.Beep(); }
            }
        }  
    }
    private static Icon CreateIcon(int value)
    {
        if (value < 50) { c = Color.FromArgb(0, 255, 0); }
        else if (value >= 80){ c = Color.OrangeRed; }
        else { c = Color.Yellow; }

        using (Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(16, 16))
        {
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bm))
            {
                using (Brush b = new SolidBrush(c))
                {
                    g.DrawString(value.ToString(), SystemFonts.DefaultFont, b, 0, 0);
                    return Icon.FromHandle(bm.GetHicon());
                } 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further research it appears that WMI cannot read CPU temperatures, I found the explanation [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9101295/msacpi-thermalzonetemperature-class-not-showing-actual-temperature)