# Get CPU temperature in CMD/POWER Shell

Tags: powershell, cmd, cpu, temperature

In my computer I am trying to get the CPU temperature. Searching on StackOverflow I found this:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>wmic /namespace:\\root\wmi PATH MSAcpi_ThermalZoneTemperature get CurrentTemperature
```

But I get this error:

```
Node - ADMIN
ERROR:
Description = Not supported
```

Comment: "Not supported" - nothing else will work on this machine. The BIOS simply doesn't support reading it.

Answer (score 24):

you can use this code :

```
function Get-Temperature {
    $t = Get-WmiObject MSAcpi_ThermalZoneTemperature -Namespace "root/wmi"
    $returntemp = @()

    foreach ($temp in $t.CurrentTemperature)
    {


    $currentTempKelvin = $temp / 10
    $currentTempCelsius = $currentTempKelvin - 273.15

    $currentTempFahrenheit = (9/5) * $currentTempCelsius + 32

    $returntemp += $currentTempCelsius.ToString() + " C : " + $currentTempFahrenheit.ToString() + " F : " + $currentTempKelvin + "K"  
    }
    return $returntemp
}

Get-Temperature
```

Comment: this is not direct CPU temp but somewhere on the MB: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17083409/1747983

Comment: Update for newer versions: `Get-CimInstance MSAcpi_ThermalZoneTemperature -Namespace "root/wmi"`

Answer (score 6):

Run the following command in Command Prompt as an **Administrator**:

`wmic /namespace:\\root\wmi PATH MSAcpi_ThermalZoneTemperature get CurrentTemperature`

This will give you some output like this:

`CurrentTemperature 3000 3010`

But make sure that you are running the cmd as an **Administrator**

Comment: Admin or no admin makes no difference. Apparently the query isn't supported on my Windows.

Comment: On my computer-
CurrentTemperature 3000 3010

its how much in °C?

Comment: @MILANSAHANA it's in 10th of Kelvin so 3010 = 301.0 K = 27.85° C

Comment: This works, but is not the CPU temperature. Result is given in units of `C*10` to avoid floats from the sensor. So in this case you need to divide the sensor value by 10 and use that for K in `C = K - 273.15`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use Open Hardware Monitor it's an open source software (MPL v2). 
You can access the command line version here:

[OpenHardwareMonitorReport.zip](https://github.com/openhardwaremonitor/openhardwaremonitor/files/1130239/OpenHardwareMonitorReport.zip)

Example part of the output:

```
PS C:\Users\myuser\OpenHardwareMonitorReport> .\OpenHardwareMonitorReport.exe

Open Hardware Monitor Report

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Version: 0.8.0.2

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Common Language Runtime: 4.0.30319.42000
Operating System: Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200.0
Process Type: 32-Bit

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Sensors

|
+- HP 00F52W (/mainboard)
|
+- Intel Core i7-3770 (/intelcpu/0)
|  +- Bus Speed      :  99.7734  99.7734  99.7784 (/intelcpu/0/clock/0)
|  +- CPU Core #1    :  3691.62  3691.62  3791.58 (/intelcpu/0/clock/1)
|  +- CPU Core #2    :  3691.62  3691.62  3791.58 (/intelcpu/0/clock/2)
|  +- CPU Core #3    :  3791.39  3791.39  3891.36 (/intelcpu/0/clock/3)
|  +- CPU Core #4    :  3691.62  3691.62  3891.36 (/intelcpu/0/clock/4)
|  +- CPU Core #1    :       42       42       43 (/intelcpu/0/temperature/0)
|  +- CPU Core #2    :       43       37       43 (/intelcpu/0/temperature/1)
|  +- CPU Core #3    :       42       35       42 (/intelcpu/0/temperature/2)
|  +- CPU Core #4    :       45       41       45 (/intelcpu/0/temperature/3)
|  +- CPU Package    :       45       43       45 (/intelcpu/0/temperature/4)
```

- [Open Hardware Monitor Official website](https://openhardwaremonitor.org/)
- link to issue where the command line version is
  linked: [#776](https://github.com/openhardwaremonitor/openhardwaremonitor/issues/776#issuecomment-313606249)
- Pending pull request with more recent version: https://github.com/openhardwaremonitor/openhardwaremonitor/pull/1115#issuecomment-616230088

Answer (score 4):

On my laptop all above gave me wrong results. Only this one was showing the CPU-Temperature in Celsius:

```
$data = Get-WMIObject -Query "SELECT * FROM Win32_PerfFormattedData_Counters_ThermalZoneInformation" -Namespace "root/CIMV2"
@($data)[0].HighPrecisionTemperature
```

I guess, that each CPU-version may have a different place/formular to get the correct CPU-temperature.

Comment: Interesting and nice twist, but not good for repeated run rates. The Query statement is slow. And don't expect to get the CPU core temp.

Comment: Thanks for this. I didn't get data from a number of sources, but this one works. My motherboard apparently has a couple of different sensors (including one that returns 0?) so I adjusted your query to this single-liner: $data = Get-WMIObject -Query "SELECT * FROM Win32_PerfFormattedData_Counters_ThermalZoneInformation" -Namespace "root/CIMV2"; @($data)[0].HighPrecisionTemperature/10 - 273.1; @($data)[1].HighPrecisionTemperature/10 - 273.1; @($data)[2].HighPrecisionTemperature

Answer (score 1):

The most stable and reliable way to get the CPU-Temperature is by using a DLL from the LibreHardwareMonitor project (which superseeds OpenHardwareMonitor).

Here is a code-snippet in Powershell:

```
# script to get the current CPU temperature, needs to run as admin/system
# requires an external DLL from the GitHub-Project "LibreHardwareMonitor"
# on first execution the script downloads the DLL from the gitHub-Project
# carsten.giese@googlemail.com


#Requires -RunAsAdministrator

cls
$dll = "$env:windir\system32\LibreHardwareMonitorLib.dll"
$storeDll = $true

if (!(Test-Path $dll)) {
    $web = [System.Net.WebClient]::new()

    # download the package:
    $url = "https://github.com/LibreHardwareMonitor/LibreHardwareMonitor/releases/download/v0.9.2/LibreHardwareMonitor-net472.zip"
    $zip = $web.DownloadData($url)

    # extract the dll:
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression
    $stream = [System.IO.Memorystream]::new()
    $stream.Write($zip,0,$zip.Length)
    $archive = [System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive]::new($stream)
    $entry = $archive.GetEntry('LibreHardwareMonitorLib.dll')
    $bytes = [byte[]]::new($entry.Length)
    [void]$entry.Open().Read($bytes, 0, $bytes.Length)

    # check MD5:
    $md5  = [Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider]::new().ComputeHash($bytes)
    $hash = [string]::Concat($md5.foreach{$_.ToString("x2")})
    if ($hash -ne 'd4a02aa7bd43a5c5ffd3d673bb20b54d') {break}

    # save the dll:
    if ($storeDll) {
        [System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes($dll, $bytes)
        Unblock-File -LiteralPath $dll
    }
} else {
    $bytes = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($dll)
    if (!$storeDll) {Remove-Item $dll -Force}
}

Add-Type -LiteralPath $dll
$monitor = [LibreHardwareMonitor.Hardware.Computer]::new()
$monitor.IsCPUEnabled = $true
$monitor.Open()
foreach ($sensor in $monitor.Hardware.Sensors) {
    if ($sensor.SensorType -eq 'Temperature' -and $sensor.Name -eq 'CPU Package'){
        $temp = $sensor.Value
        break
    }
}
$monitor.Close()
write-host "CPU-Package Temperature = $temp°C" -f y
```

Answer (score 0):

With new sensor, or with what I have and with elevation.
It also shows critical temperature and percentage (in Celsius)
It leaves a file Temperatures.txt for easy debugging, and the xml with serialized object from sensors

```
function Get-Temperature {
    $TempFormat = "#"
    $TempFile = "temperature"

    $Command = 'Get-WmiObject MSAcpi_ThermalZoneTemperature -Namespace "root/wmi" ' + " > $pwd\$TempFile.txt"
    $Command = 'Get-WmiObject MSAcpi_ThermalZoneTemperature -Namespace "root/wmi" ' + " | Export-Clixml $pwd\$TempFile.xml"

    $p = Start-Process -Verb runas -FilePath "powershell" -ArgumentList $command -WorkingDirectory $pwd -PassThru
    $p.WaitForExit()

    $t = Import-Clixml pippo.xml

    $returntemp = @()

    foreach ($Sensor in $t)
    {
    $Active = if($sensor.Active){"On "}else{"Off"}
    $temp = $Sensor.CurrentTemperature
    $Critical = $Sensor.CriticalTripPoint

    $currentTempKelvin = $temp / 10
    $currentTempCelsius = $currentTempKelvin - 273.15
    $currentTempFahrenheit = (9/5) * $currentTempCelsius + 32

    $StrKelvin = $currentTempKelvin.ToString($TempFormat).PadLeft(3, " ")
    $StrCelsius = $currentTempCelsius.ToString($TempFormat).PadLeft(3, " ")
    $StrFahrenheit = $currentTempFahrenheit.ToString($TempFormat).PadLeft(3, " ")

    $CriticalKelvin = $Critical / 10
    $CriticalCelsius = $CriticalKelvin - 273.15
    $CriticalFahrenheit = (9/5) * $CriticalCelsius + 32

    $StrCritKelvin = $CriticalKelvin.ToString($TempFormat).PadRight(3, " ")
    $StrCritCelsius = $CriticalCelsius.ToString($TempFormat).PadRight(3, " ")
    $StrCritFahrenheit = $CriticalFahrenheit.ToString($TempFormat).PadRight(3, " ")

    $PerCrit = ($currentTempCelsius/$CriticalCelsius * 100)
    $StrPerCrit = $PerCrit.ToString($TempFormat).PadLeft(3, " ")

    $returntemp += "$Active $StrPerCrit% $StrCelsius/$StrCritCelsius C : $StrFahrenheit/$StrCritFahrenheit  F : $StrKelvin/$StrCritKelvin K - " + $Sensor.InstanceName 
    }
    return $returntemp
}

Get-Temperature
```

Comment: Import-Clixml pippo.xml where does pippo.xml get created?

Answer (score -1):

According to [the answer on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9101295/msacpi-thermalzonetemperature-class-not-showing-actual-temperature) :

> To get the exact temperature of CPU (and every core) you **need to write
> kernel drivers,** what is much more complicated.
>
> CurrentTemperature returns temperature at some thermal zone which is
> **somewhere on motherboard**.

This would explain why some of the answers on this page return a temperature, but it's wildly different to the actual CPU temp.