# Windows Powershell sometimes outputs no values (temperature sensor)

Tags: windows, powershell

From time to time it happens that no temperature sensors are displayed. I use Powershell to read the values and that works often. I would like to know why Windows sometimes does not return anything. Is that on my laptop, software or what?

```
powershell Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_PerfFormattedData_Counters_ThermalZoneInformation |Select-Object Name,Temperature
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The actual class is **MSAcpi_ThermalZoneTemperature**. Use the below function:

```
function Get-Temperature {
    $t = Get-WmiObject MSAcpi_ThermalZoneTemperature -Namespace "root/wmi"
    $currentTempKelvin = $t.CurrentTemperature / 10
    $currentTempCelsius = $currentTempKelvin - 273.15
    $currentTempFahrenheit = (9/5) * $currentTempCelsius + 32
    return $currentTempCelsius.ToString() + " C : " + $currentTempFahrenheit.ToString() + " F : " + $currentTempKelvin + "K" 
}
```

**Alternative:**

```
$strComputer = "."

$objWMi = get-wmiobject -namespace root\WMI -computername localhost -Query "Select * from MSAcpi_ThermalZoneTemperature"

foreach ($obj in $objWmi)
{
    write-host "Active:" $obj.Active
    write-host "ActiveTripPoint:" $obj.ActiveTripPoint
    write-host "ActiveTripPointCount:" $obj.ActiveTripPointCount
    write-host "CriticalTripPoint:" $obj.CriticalTripPoint
    write-host "CurrentTemperature:" $obj.CurrentTemperature
    write-host "InstanceName:" $obj.InstanceName
    write-host "PassiveTripPoint:" $obj.PassiveTripPoint
    write-host "Reserved:" $obj.Reserved
    write-host "SamplingPeriod:" $obj.SamplingPeriod
    write-host "ThermalConstant1:" $obj.ThermalConstant1
    write-host "ThermalConstant2:" $obj.ThermalConstant2
    write-host "ThermalStamp:" $obj.ThermalStamp
    write-host
    write-host "########"
    write-host
}
```

Reference link : [Thermal Zone Info](http://www.activexperts.com/admin/scripts/wmiscripts/powershell/0211/)

Hope it helps.

Comment: If you have multiple CPU's, `Get-WmiObject MSAcpi_ThermalZoneTemperature -Namespace "root/wmi"` returns multiple instances and your function throws an exception trying to divide an array by 10. Other than that, very good to know, thanks.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers: Then arraylist should do the work and also with try catch :)

Answer (score 0):

For some reason windows doesn't always return the CPU value for `MSAcpi_ThermalZoneTemperature` an alternative is to use Open Hardware Monitor Report
[Get CPU temperature in CMD/POWER Shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39738494/get-cpu-temperature-in-cmd-power-shell/61542386#61542386)

Answer (score 0):

```
powershell Get-CimInstance Win32_PerfFormattedData_Counters_ThermalZoneInformation | findstr /i "Name Temperature"
```

Windows don't "return" value because OEM decided their sensors won't cooperate with windows wmi(in short).

Start > Run or WinKey+R
wmimgmt.msc (and then press [Enter])

PS. - cmd

```
wmic /namespace:\\root\wmi PATH MSAcpi
```