# How to get Virtual Server Temperature via PowerShell?

Tags: windows, powershell, wmi

I can get the Physical Server temperature by using the

```
Win32_PerfFormattedData_Counters_ThermalZoneInformation (temperature)
```

command in PowerShell.

However, the same command is not possible in the virtual machine.

Can I know how to get server temperature in a virtual machine?

Comment: Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41792575/934946). It might be worth a try.

Comment: It's not possible, because `VM's have no temperature or other stuff related to that class` ; as ***there are no physical components of VMs (aka CPU, HD, MB, etc.) to generate any)***. Thus you can only do this on the VMHost/local machine. All VM’s on that VMHost would report the same as the VMHost itself, so no real point in doing that. What/who lead you to believe that VM's had all the attributes of a physical box? Just curious. Note: Vendor hardware sensors and Windows can/will report different things. Just saying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A virtual server (VM) as the name suggests is virtual and has no physical presence. So it cannot have a temperature.

You can only get the temperature of the physical host on which the VM resides.

You will need to query the temp of the physical host.