# batch or powershell method with timestamp log for a program?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd, mining

I am a miner and i mine from gpu. Sometimes there is a CUDA error that stops mining, I am looking for a batch script which monitors the temperature of all gpu's and if somehow the temperature falls below 50 for 2 mins continuously then create a log with timestamp in a text file and restart the program.

I have tried previous powershell scripts which are of no use. If you all have any other alternative please suggest.
This is code i tried but its based on memory thats not what i want i want to monitor temperature.

```
while ($true) {
   Get-Process calc -ea 0 | where { $_.PM -le 10MB } | foreach {
        $Path = $_.Path
        [bool]$Ping = Test-Connection 8.8.8.8 -Quiet
        if ($Path -and $Ping) {
            Stop-Process $_ -Force
            Start-Process $Path
        }
    }
    sleep -s 1
}
```

Comment: Batch has no way of retrieving the GPU's temperature. You'll have to find some program to do that for you.

Comment: powershell sounds like the way to do this. What have you tried so far? Asking for someone to provide scripts or find them online is not what we do here.

Comment: @JamesZ  i posted wht i tried. THANKs btw .If u have any alternate solution rather than monitoring plz share

Comment: If u have any alternate solution rather than monitoring plz share @SomethingDark

Comment: You obviously need a command, program or a script to check the temperature. If you can't do that, anything else is pointless -- so that's where you need to start, instead of asking someone to share scripts.

Comment: Thanks I realized m wrong with my words here. I have edited my post. @JamesZ

Comment: I might have something, will just have to remember tomorrow.

Comment: plz m waiting there is no good solution out there @AbrahamZinala

Comment: I'll try to find it today.

Comment: Tried everything sir only monitoring temperature is the best method . plz help me sir @AbrahamZinala

Comment: @AbrahamZinala any luck finding it ?

Comment: Yes I can't comment post it since your question is closed lol. I will post somewhere else and will let you know

Comment: See if this helps, or if at leasts points you in the right direction: https://community.spiceworks.com/scripts/show/4960-get-gpuutilization. it uses `Get-Counter` to get the info, but it can be tweaked. Just not sure how it will work against a mining rig.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala the link does not work

Comment: Not sure what to tell you. I just posted it, so you can probably search for "Get GPU Utilization Spiceworks Scripts* on Google, or something.

Comment: Here's the root page: https://community.spiceworks.com/scripts?language=3

Comment: @AbrahamZinala I see the script sir . but it does'nt do anything

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't do anything? Lol did you dot source the script and run the function?

Answer (score 1):

you could take a look at the `PSHardwareMonitor` powershell module from this [Link](https://github.com/ThomasWilla/PSHardwareMonitoring)

> This Powershell Module catch the min/max/current value from the CPU and GPU temperature. This Module is based on the OpenHardwaremonitoring Project and will not use the default Windows CIM Class. Thereby all CPUs and GPUs are supported. For more Information see https://openhardwaremonitor.org/

Also you could check @saftargholi reply from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39738567/4165074)

Comment: I dnt see any commands in openhardwaremonitor its graphical sir i need command based. @MahmoudMoawad

Comment: Did you checked this link https://github.com/ThomasWilla/PSHardwareMonitoring

Comment: Sry now i checked that. i am facing problem with enabling m using this 

$HARDWAREMONITOR.EnableGPU = $true|$false {default: $False}  

Error:Unexpected token '{' in expression or statement

Comment: That's a syntax error.