# How to get motherboard sensor readings in C#

Tags: c#, .net, performance, accelerometer, sensors

I'm trying to get any temp/fanspeed/accelerometer readings from my motherboard in C#
I have done a lot of research and I know its not easy, but it has to be possible to get something I can work with.

I have tried using motherboardmonitor.net but I can't figure out how to incorporate the dll into my program.

I have tried "using motherboardmonitor" with the motherboardmonitor.DLL i downloaded. But there is absolutely no documentation on how to use it. Im just fumbling around with it at the moment to no avail.

And I have tried using the sensor.dll but I dont think i have enough knowledge to go any further.

Comment: Are you asking how to add a library resource to a C# project in Visual Studio?

Comment: Can you please link to where you downloaded motherboardmonitor.net?

Comment: Getting the source code might help you - there may be documentation in the source code that isn't included in the dll: http://sourceforge.net/projects/mbmdotnet/files/

Comment: At what step did things go bad?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/wkze6zky(v=VS.80).aspx

Comment: Or have you tried using the Object Browser to discover anything?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example of what you are trying to achieve. Hope it's helpful.

http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/1723879

It might not be a full solution, but it should get you started in the right direction.

The following is usefull too:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/34f0fa55-567b-4a98-a29d-b92a5c9b5f8f/
[CPU temperature monitoring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923984/cpu-temperature-monitoring-c-sharp)