# Raspberry Pi CPU Temp

Tags: c#, powershell, raspberry-pi, windows-10-iot-core

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 running Windows 10 IoT Core. My question is; would it be possible, or is there a way to monitor the CPU temperature of the device either via a remote PowerShell connection, locally on the device in the command line console or if all else fails using a C# deployed app on the device?

I confess to being a C# noob, hence it being my third option.

Why?... I'm planning on building a custom case out of Lego for a stack of several devices and want to assess whether I need to purchase a bunch of heat sinks and cooling fans etc.

Many thanks for your time and assistance.

Comment: have you tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923984/cpu-temperature-monitoring)?

Comment: Any code you use locally on the RPi3 can be invoked from Powershell, so you need to write the code that reads the CPU temp sensor first. A local application though should be the *first* option - you can't poll 100s of IoT devices nor can you secure them. The secure way is for the device to post to a well known and trusted API/server

Comment: @GeraldSchneider the OP is asking about IoT, not WMI. An RPi has a lot of sensors, one of which simply happens to be related to CPU temperature

Answer (score 3):

I hope this can guide you to the right track.

In order to access to low-level BCM2836 peripherals that the IoT SDK or PowerShell client does not provide, you'll need to write your own drivers.

You can follow the code samples from https://github.com/ms-iot/bsp/tree/master/drivers, it's written under WDK framework so you'll need to get yourself familiar with that in order to get started.

I guess eventually you'll end up with something like one of those samples under the drivers sample.

When you're done, deploy your driver follow this tutorial https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/win10/samples/driverlab3

I'm not 100 percent sure this is the right way to go, but if someone could correct me or point out a better solution, I would be more than happy to learn from it.