# Get CPU temperature from Raspberry Pi with Windows IOT Core

Tags: powershell, raspberry-pi, windows-iot-core-10

Is there a way to get the CPU temperature from a Raspberry Pi with Windows 10 IoT Core, much like you can get running "vcgencmd measure_temp" in Raspbian? Unfortunately Windows Dashboard App Manager "SystemPerformance.htm" only shows CPU performance and PowerShell for Windows IOT Core does not include the "Get-WmiObject" Cmdlet to have run the script on this page: https://gist.github.com/jeffa00/9577816. Are there other alternatives? :(

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try Open Hardware Monitor Report it's an open source software.
[Get CPU temperature in CMD/POWER Shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39738494/get-cpu-temperature-in-cmd-power-shell/61542386#61542386)

Comment: Thanks for the hint. It does help on my Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I believe WMI cmdlets are not there but CIM cmdlets are. I am also unsure if the WMI class you need is there. But using the CIM cmdlet would look something like this:

```
$t = Get-CimInstance MSAcpi_ThermalZoneTemperature -Namespace "root/wmi"
```

Comment: Unfortunately running that Get-CimInstance MSAcpi_ThermalZoneTemperature -Namespace "root/wmi" I get.. 
    Get-CimInstance : Not supported 
    + CategoryInfo          : NotImplemented: root/wmi:MSAcpi_ThermalZoneTemperature:String) [Get-CimInstance], CimExc 
   eption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x8004100c,Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimCmdlets.GetCimInstanceCommand

Comment: I seem to be looking what was posted on this other thread and the answer/solution someone posted is not one very encouraging ... :( ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37703705/raspberry-pi-cpu-temp

Comment: Yeah, that means the class "MSAcpi_ThermalZoneTemperature" isn't there to query.