# How can I get RaspberryPI CPU temperature on IoT Core?

Tags: windows-10-iot-core

Using the SenseHat the temperature readings come back very hot.
Is there a way to get the CPU temperature on the RapsberryPi with Win10IoTCore to compensate?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Raspberry Pi CPU Temp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37703705/raspberry-pi-cpu-temp)